# Nested loop arrays .length property

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, nested

I am rendering data from a news API source.  I use a nested loop to go through each topic for the length of the array that comes back (it is limited to 5 but can be less).

the nested loop should be limited to the length of the array however I get undefined.
I am trying to use `topNews[i].data[j].length` but I keep getting undefined.  Is there a different way of getting the length of a nested array in a nested loop? The code below works but if a source has less than 5 then I get undefined and it breaks.  If I could limit it to the length it would stop rather than breaking.

```
function renderData() {
  let html = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < twitterTrends.length; i++) {
    html += "<section class='news'>";
    html += `<h2>${twitterTrends[i]}</h2>`;
    html += "<ul class='articles'>";
    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      html += `<li>
        ${
          topNews[i].data[j].image_url
            ? `<div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url('${topNews[i].data[j].image_url}')"></div>`
            : ""
        }
        <h3><a href="${topNews[i].data[j].url}" target="_blank">${
        topNews[i].data[j].title
      }</a></h3>
        <p>${topNews[i].data[j].snippet}</p>
      </li>`;
    }
    html += "</ul></section>";
  }
  html +=
    "<button type='button' class='js-restart button'>Refresh Results</button>";
  $("#results").html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++)
```

to

```
for (let j = 0; j < topNews[i].data.length; j++)
```

Comment: I have it up here https://gmacerola.github.io/twitter-trend-news/

Comment: @gmacerola Can you put up an example showing the error?

Comment: For some reason now it is working! Thank you so much @nzn !